# How can i extract metdata from django models

Tags: python, django, angularjs, django-models, metadata

Suppose i have this model in django

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Now i want to create a serializer in REST to get all the metadata from the models.

Like the resulting JSON should contain

```
 //rough example
    {
    first_name: {max_length: 30},
    last_name: {max_length:30}
    }
```

My Aim is to get the meta data on the fly and then create forms dynamically using angularJS schema forms

Any idea on how can i read that meta data for models

Comment: You can use [django-angular](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular) to build your forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a Model's fields and their metadata like this:

```py
def get_model_metadata(model_class, meta_whitelist=[]):
  field_list = model_class._meta.fields
  return_data = {}
  for field in field_list:
    field_name = field.name
    field_meta = field.__dict__
    return_meta = {}
    for meta_name in field_meta:
      if meta_name in meta_whitelist:
        return_meta[meta_name] = field_meta[meta_name]
    if len(return_meta) > 0:
      return_data[field_name] = return_meta
  return return_data
```

Usage:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
get_model_metadata(User, meta_whitelist=['max_length'])
```

Returns:

```py
{
  'username': {'max_length': 30},
  'first_name': {'max_length': 30},
  'last_name': {'max_length': 30},
  'is_active': {'max_length': None},
  'email': {'max_length': 75},
  'is_superuser': {'max_length': None},
  'is_staff': {'max_length': None},
  'last_login': {'max_length': None},
  'password': {'max_length': 128},
  u'id': {'max_length': None},
  'date_joined': {'max_length': None}
}
```

Improvements to this method would include blacklist of field metadata, whitelist/blacklist for fields, and maybe a boolean for not showing metadata that has None value.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get that information through introspection, cf dir(Person._meta) : you could use Person._meta.get_all_field_names() and then Person._meta.get_field_by_name('first_name') to get the field and extract more information from it.